# Is it possible to clear all intervals set within NGZone?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, zone

I have a Angular2 component that has a custom 3rd party JQuery plugin (which we must use and can't change) initialized within it in the OnInit event.However this 3rd party library makes liberal use of setIntervals. If I navigate away from the view the intervals are still active and on other views they keep triggering the widget behaviour.

The 3rd party component has no way to destroy it or clear intervals (which isn't great). I had hoped to just call destroy() or similar in Angular2 OnDestroy method.

I thought I should be able to use Zone to clean up.  I did the following:

```
constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, public zone: NgZone) {
    }

ngOnInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        $(this.elementRef).3rdPartyWidgetStart();
    });}

ngOnDestroy() {
    var componentzone=this.zone;
    //So do something here to clear intervals set within Zone???
}
```

I thought that it would clear the  intervals when I navigate away. However that doesn't seem to be the case. I also tried `run` instead of `runOutsideAngular` and it didn't seem to help.  I then thought that Zone should know all of the intervals that have been set and I can clear them through that. It does appear to know them however doesn't seem possible to get access to the list and clear? Any ideas using Angular 2 RC - alternatively if I am just doing something totally wrong with Zones let me know. This is all new to me

Comment: How would this be done when the jQuery component is used outside Angular?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - When I examine the NGZone it seems to be aware of the intervals that have been set within it? My understanding was that NGZone intercepted all calls to SetInterval, SetTimout, Alert etc. This post in the zone github https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/211 seems to suggest it is possible but I don't understand how. NGZone doesn't seem to expose away to change the hooks for SetInterval etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should say, that you are doing it on your own risk. Use Zone directly:

```
    Zone.current.fork({
        name: 'jquery', onScheduleTask: (parentZoneDelegate: ZoneDelegate, currentZone: Zone, targetZone: Zone,
                                                  task: Task)=>
        {
            if(task.source === 'setInterval'){
                console.log('capture', task);
                //data has handleId property, interval id
                this.interval = task.data; 
            }
            return parentZoneDelegate.scheduleTask(targetZone, task);
        }
    }).run(()=>
    {
        setInterval(()=>
        {
            console.log('jquery interval', Zone.current);
        }, 5000);
    });
```

Somewhere in the code:

```
clearInterval(this.interval.handleId);
```

This code most probably lacks some checks, read documentation. Also i am not sure if angular is ok with that.

Comment: So it isn't actually possible to use NGZone? You have to drop to Zone?  Any idea what sort of issues Angular could experience as a result - anything to watch out for?

Comment: NgZone is just abstraction that has api specific to angular2, it does not expose zone methods. You can find its source code on github.

Answer (score 1):

1) `run` vs `runOutsideAngular`

When calling `runOutsideAngular`, the change detection will not get triggered after async operations (`setTimeout`, evetns, XHR, ..) initiated from your plugin.

When calling `run` (a better is to call `3rdPartyWidgetStart` directly) the change detection would execute after any async op.

Pick whatever way that works for your projects (ie do you need to run the CD after setTiemout, events, ... ?).

2) Clear the setTimeouts

What you could do is to fork the current zone passing a `ZoneDelegate` that would accumulate the timer ids and cancel them in your `ngOnDestroy`.

But the best way to deal with this is probably to fix the jQuery plugin.

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the time to reply. Would love to fix the 3rd party plugin - so much easier technically.... Any idea on documentation for ZoneDelgate for NGZone. NGZone doesn't seem to have fork options.